# How to invoke chrome extension using playwright

Tags: puppeteer, playwright

I have a Chrome extension named "Easyview Reader view". Chromium is able to recognize this extension. Is there a way I can open a web page and run this extension and top of it .

Example - As a browser operation :

Step 1: Open the page - https://privacycenter.instagram.com/policy/
Step 2: Right click on the page and select "Easyview Reader view" extension

By doing this extension gets applied to the web page I am interested in.

```
import {chromium}  from 'playwright'; // Web scraper Library
import * as path from 'path';

(async () => {
    const pathToExtension = path.join("~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Extensions/icnekagcncdgpdnpoecofjinkplbnocm/0.8.3_0", '.')
    const userDataDir = '~/Source-Code/sample-nodejs/temp/';
  const browserContext = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(userDataDir,{
    headless: false,
    args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
      `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`
    ]
  });
  const page = await browserContext.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://instagram.com/legal/privacy/", { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 60000 });
  //await page.click("button", { button: "right" });

  //////////     TODO ////////////
    await browserContext.close();
})();
```

If it is not possible through playwright , can it be done using Puppeteer ?